# hide selected value of a select list, when list is open

Tags: html, css, select, placeholder

I have a dropdown `select` list, from which I can choose a country. the first option is: choose your country.

```
<select>
      <option selected disabled value=''>Choose your country</option>
      <option value="1">Canada</option>
      <option value="2">France</option>

</select>
```

But when I click to open the list, I can see choose your country in the options. Is there a way to hide this option from the list, and only show it as a placeholder before any selection is made?

Comment: My question is if you want this behavior what if you don't want to select anything ?

Answer (score -1):

Hides the default option from appearing in the list:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZT2ZV/

IMO the better solution would be to use something like:  http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

```
 <select>
        <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose your country</option>
          <option value="1">Canada</option>
          <option value="2">France</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I formatted, to try and help, but now please explain your code. And why it works.

Answer (score -1):

Use `display:none;` on your first value:

```
<select>
      <option value="" selected disabled style="display:none;">Choose your country</option>
      <option value="2">Canada</option>
      <option value="3">France</option>
</select>
```

try  http://jsfiddle.net/uaF93/